# How to download a file as Byte Array from AWS S3 Storage?

Tags: c#, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can download a file from the Amazon S3 Storage with below code,

```
var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(txt_Accesskey.Text, txt_Secretkey.Text, bucketRegion);
GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();
request.BucketName = bucketName;
request.Key = "Sample.txt";
GetObjectResponse response = s3Client.GetObject(request);
response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(@"C:\Desktop\Sample.txt");
```

But, I want to download these files as Byte Array. Can anyone please give me a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just quickly looking at the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client_GetObject.htm), you maybe able to do this

```
using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
   bytes = response.ResponseStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: According to Reference Document, GetObjectResponse.ResponseStream is Return Stream instead of Byte[].

Comment: @MuhammadUsamaAlam, you are absolutely correct thanks